# PHP- First query overridden second query issue

Tags: php, mysql

Can a php query get overridden? The reason i am asking is due to the fact i believe one of my queries is getting overridden from another query in the same page. They call different tables however, the second query is now not working. But if i copy and paste the overridden query into another php page is works as expected.

FIRST QUERY(S)

```
 if (isset($_POST['update'])) {
    $a = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST['a']);
    $b = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST['b']);
    $c = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST['c']);

    $insert = "INSERT INTO details
    ( a , b , c) 
   VALUES
   ( ?, ?, ?) 
   ON DUPLICATE KEY 
   UPDATE a  = VALUES (a), b  = VALUES(b) , c  = VALUES(c)";
    $row = mysqli_prepare($dbc, $insert);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($row, 'sss',$a $b, $c);
    /* execute query */
    $execute = mysqli_stmt_execute($row);
    if ($execute) {
        echo "success";
    } else {
        echo "error ";
    }
  }     
    ?>
    <?php
    $upda_form = $dbc->query("SELECT * FROM Details");
    $get_res = $upda_form->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH);

    //session_start does not work here 
    $_SESSION['a'] = $get_res['a'];
    $_SESSION['b'] = $get_res['b'];
    $_SESSION['c'] = $get_res['c'];

    ?>
```

SECOND QUERY

```
 <select name="b" id="b">
                    <option>Choose cuisine</option>
                    <?php

                    $get_cats = "SELECT * FROM Rest_Category";
                    $run_cats = mysqli_query($dbc, $get_cats);
                    while ($row_cats = mysqli_fetch_array($run_cats)) {


                        $Cuisine_category = $row_cats['Cuisine_category'];

                        echo"<option value='$Cuisine_category'>$Cuisine_category</option>";
                    }
                    ?>
                </select>
```

The dropdown menu is meant to display all the cuisine category names for the DB, however, all it does on this page is display "Choose cuisine" but when the code is copy and pasted in other php pages, all the categories show.

The drop downs id is called in the first query, however, i have deleted all the "B" specifications and still no change. So i am now wondering if the first query is overridden the second query, and how to fix it.

Comment: You should not be using BOTH escaping and variable binding.

Comment: Your "second query" has 2 queries. Also, you're missing OO mysqli and functional mysqli. Pick one or the other.

Comment: @Terminus sorry it is the first query, has two queries. I was using functional mysqli but was advised to change it. Thank you

Comment: Ok... you still need to use just OO or just functional.